# Calculating post-collision velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, collision

Consider two persons $p1$ and $p2$ of the same mass , such that they are **together**  moving rightward with a velocity of $v/2$

Now person $p1$ pushes $p2$ in the left direction. According to newton's third law, $p1$ gets pushed in the right direction with same force ,$F$.

Consider these calculations:

```
in the interial frame of  p1 and p2,
momentum before push = 0 ==> [1]

momentum after push = m(x) + m(y) ==> [2]

from law of conservation of momentum, [1] = [2] ==> m(x + y) = 0
since mass can't be 0, x + y = 0 ==> 3

since force on both objects is same and their masses are also same, 
they would end up having same and opposite acceleration, 
hence after the push, both will have same and opposite final velocity 
which gives rise to:

so, y = -x  ==> [4]
```

Now, consider person $p2$. In the intertial frame of $p1$ & $p2$, if final velocity of $p2$ is $-x$, then what is the velocity with which $p2$ moves after the push, as in reference to a person $p3$ who is outside their frame of reference?

Comment: Why moving with $\frac{v}{2}$ and not $v$?? And by the way, if both have same momentum, how one pushes another?

Comment: "hence after the push, both will have same final velocity" is **not** true.  One will have an increase in the rightward velocity and the other a decrease in the rightward velocity.  The **magnitudes** of the accelerations will be the same but their **directions** will be opposite to one another.

Comment: What @Farcher says is correct. Another way to think about it: since they're in an inertial reference frame, assume their initial velocity is 0. When one pushes the other he gains a positive velocity, and the other gains a negative velocity, of the same magnitude.

Comment: @barrycarter I have edited the question, could you please answer now?

Comment: I upvoted @PeterTsrunchev's excellent answer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Galilean relativity (pretty sure that is what you mean/need), you just add up the velocities. So $ V_{p_1} =v/2+x$ and $V_{p_2}=v/2+y=v/2-x$